# Multiple Git accounts

Tags: git

I am running windows 7 and have installed an Ubuntu   machine using virtual box. After much effort, I managed to connect through from the Ubuntu virtual machine to my windows folder.

My plan is to run ruby on rails on the Ubuntu machine, but keep the folders on my windows 7 machine. I will do editing on the windows machine and everything else on the Ubuntu machine. This is meant to be much faster.

I have already been developing on the windows machine so have a version of git installed on window 7 with many branches, at c:\sites\rails_projects.  There also appears to be a version of git installed on Ubuntu. Ideally I would like to use the git on Ubuntu to manage the repositories on my windows machine.

My question is how to do this, i.e. can I just go to the windows folders at c:\sites\rails_projects from Ubuntu and use the git version in Ubuntu, or do I need somehow to hand over the repositories from the windows version of git to the Ubuntu installation of git? My concern is that if I use two installations of git on the same folders that things will get very confused.

thank you

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Git on the side where you program. You don't need to use both.

Note 1: The state for a git repository is entirely written in its .git/ directory.

Note 2: There is no such a thing as a git account.

Comment: To add to that, you can just install msysgit, which is the port of git to Windows.